# Maven provided dependency needed for goal

Tags: maven

I have a provided dependency in my maven build - the database drivers which are installed and provided in the Tomcat instance. So far so good.

But I also use [Flyway](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/) and want to execute a manual (`mvn flyway:migrate`) migration from my build. In that I need the dependencies. Of course I could integrate Flyway in a way that it checks the database on start of the web application, but I would like to solve the Maven approach.

How can this be done? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [maven profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) with the dependecies you need to run Flyway and you can activate the profile in this way:

```
 mvn flyway:migrate -P flywayProfile
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it is also possible to specify dependencies under the plugin section, see [How to override a plugin's dependency in Maven](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2008/04/how-to-override-a-plugins-dependency-in-maven/). This solved my problem.

It should be noted that if you use additional repositories for your dependencies, you have to provide a `pluginRepositories` tag in that case.

Comment: Is this solution working? I used this only to override plugin dependencies, not for adding new dependencies.

Comment: Yes it worked and I found it easier than introducing profiles but of course your solution is also valid.